# Swift: expressions was too complex to be solved in reasonable time

Tags: ios, swift

Now, I've seen this swift error posted all over stackoverflow. However, the way they handle it won't seem to work in my situation.

```
if ( 
        fieldType == "checkbox" ||
        fieldType == "time" ||
        fieldType == "birthdate" ||
        fieldType == "datetime" ||
        fieldType == "phone" ||
        fieldType == "payment" ||
        fieldType == "stripe" ||
        fieldType == "paypal" ||
        fieldType == "paypalpro" ||
        fieldType == "address" ||
        fieldType == "2co")

{
```

Not sure how I can fix it. There must be some way to lower the complexity of it.

Comment: Read the second part of the error message: "Consider breaking the expression down into distinct expressions". Consider it!

Comment: I would put them in an array and use contains

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Sorry, didn't see your comment until after I'd entered my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is just start with an array of literals:

```
    let fieldType = "Howdy"
    let possibilities = ["checkbox","time"] // ... add the others too...
    if find(possibilities, fieldType) != nil { // or: if contains(possibilities,fieldType)
    }
```

Comment: aren't we supposed to not answer dupes?

Comment: Yeah, all that happened while I was typing. :(